# Wait for specific response, then execute next command

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[project-id]:[region]:[instance-id]=tcp:5432 -credential_file=serviceaccount.json &
sleep 5
node app.js
```

First, I want the `cloud_sql_proxy` command to run. After 5 seconds, I also want the `node` command to run. The first command (`cloud_sql_proxy`) is a command that keeps running, so a `wait` does not work here (it keeps waiting).

When the `cloud_sql_proxy` command is 'ready', it outputs "Ready for new connections". **Is there anyway I can "capture" this output, check if it "Ready for new connections", and if so, execute the second command (`node`)?** In that way, I do not longer need the `sleep 5` and I'm sure the `node` command is not running if there is a problem with the `cloud_sql_proxy` command.

Comment: You can redirect the output of `cloud_sql_proxy` to a file and then `grep` that file for the required output to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your proxy process runs in the background, the normal ways of capturing output don't work (ex: `var=$(echo "test command")`)

The easiest way to capture the output you want would be to redirect all output to a file, then check that file for the string you need.

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m

# Added output redirection for stdout and stderr
./cloud_sql_proxy --add_your_options_here >filename 2>&1 &

# Wait for up to 5 seconds for the service to be ready.
for attempt in $(seq 1 5); do
    sleep 1
    if grep -q "Ready for new connections" filename; then
        break
    fi
    if [[ attempt -eq 5 ]]; then
        echo "Error launching sql proxy - see 'filename' for command output."
        exit
    fi
done

node app.js
```

To view output, `cat filename`.

This solution should work as long as the file is being truncated every time you run the script. If not, the `grep` will return true due to "stale" text in the file.

Comment: Thank you! It works. This is a solution I would never come up with. I was trying to save the output into a file and reading out that file, but it was empty, like you said, it's a background process.

Comment: For cleanliness you should probably use `mktemp` to get a unique filename for use, and then `rm` the file before running `node`.  It'll still be "open" for as long as the proxy process runs but it'll be automatically cleaned up when the process terminates.

Comment: @StephenHarris: I added "> filename" to clear the content, but when I open the container and do "cat filename" I still get the output, so that's not working. I'm going to try your approach now.